# Golang: Send errors using Http Header

Tags: go, error-handling, header, http-headers

I want  to send all the errors that I get to another service(Consume my service) using Http Header

Ex: I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
func main() {
  http.HandleFunc("/", foo)
  log.Println("Listening...")
  http.ListenAndServe(":6001", nil)
  }

func foo(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  w.Header().Set("successfull", "A Go Web Server")

  fi := path.Join("templates/VastPlayer", "TempVide_.txt")
  tmpl, err := template.ParseFiles(fi)

        if err != nil {
            w.Header().Set("Error", err.Error())
            http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
            }
        if  err := tmpl.Execute(w, ""); err != nil{
              w.Header().Set("Error", err.Error())  
              http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
          }
  }
```

if I give a valide template I got **"successfull" : "A Go Web Server"** on the Header, but if I give no existing tempalte I got **502 Bad Gateway** and this on the header

```
HTTP/1.1 502 Bad Gateway
Server: nginx/1.8.0
Date: Mon, 06 Jul 2015 15:19:31 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 574
Connection: keep-alive
```

I want to know if there is a way to send the Error that i got through a header,
I mean **templates/VastPlayer/TempVide_.txt: no such file or directory**

Thank you in advance

Comment: how are you going to resolve the `ParseFiles` incorrect path issue?

Comment: why doesn't work , this is my question when I check the header don't find "Error" on the header. I tiried without **panic** doesn't work. I don't want to resolve **ParseFiles ** I just want to send the message through a header

Comment: @Aziz: it doesn't work because you're calling `panic` and aborting the handler. Don't do that.

Comment: @JimB I tried without `panic`,it doesn't work.

Comment: Put some debugging statements in there to make sure it's doing what you expect. We can't tell what this code does out of context, (plus `job_1.Complete(health.Panic)` sounds like it might panic too). Please make a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) if you can't figure out what's going on.

Comment: @JimB I edited my question I hope that it's clear now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `502` response, is coming from nginx, so first test the go server directly on port 6001. Also, look at the output for your server's process, there error will be printed there.

After you set your error header and call `http.Error` you need a `return`, otherwise you're going to continue executing the rest of the handler. Since `tmpl` is nil if there was an error, calling `tmpl.Execute` causes a nil pointer dereference, and the server panics.

(And you start out setting a "successful" header, so that will always be there, even if there's an error.)

Comment: Great the problem was the `return` I put it after the `http.Error` and it works perfectly now. Gracias.